# Granger Causality test pre-conditions

Tags: time-series, stationarity, cointegration, unit-root, granger-causality

I am trying to analyse the causation between individual stock returns and index returns. I have taken the log return values of both stock and index values. Unit root test suggest that the values are stationary; but Johansen cointegration test resulted with two cointegrating equations in both Trace and Eigenvalues.

Can I apply Granger causality test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have two time series, then the univariate unit-root test results coincide nicely with the cointegration test results. Both indicate that the series are stationary. Moreoever, this is as expected; financial returns are normally considered *not* to have unit roots.

However, you could think about cointegration between the stock price and the level of the stock index. They will both be integrated of order one (as they are cumulative sums of processes that do not contain unit roots, as per your current analysis), so there is at least the theoretical potential for cointegration. Whether cointegration would make sense in practice is another question and depends on the application. Here your subject-matter expertise will come in handy.

In any case, once you decide on presence/absence of cointegration between the stock price and the level of the stock index, you can proceed to Granger causality testing.

- In case of cointegration you would use the Toda-Yamamoto procedure described clearly in Dave Giles blog post ["Testing for Granger Causality"](http://davegiles.blogspot.no/2011/04/testing-for-granger-causality.html).
- In case of no cointegration, you may run a simple vector autoregression and test for Granger causality in the regular way.

Comment: I have taken the stock and index price data and found the order of integration as 1 (q) , there after i have tried to find the number of lags . If i have taken maximum number of lags to check  as 5 the AIC lag selection criterion has shown me best as lag 1 (p) , but i cannot take lag 1 as p>q . Only i have got different lag result if i set my maximum number of lags to check as 20. Then i got the AIC best lag to select as 19 which is greater than order of intergration. I am really not sure if such high numbered lag is valid to create a model. Please kindly provide me your insights

Comment: *Lag order* and *order of integration* are not related. One does not depend on the other.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! should i take the optimal lag length for my model as 1 or 19 as mentioned to you in the last comment?

Comment: Do you mean the VAR model that will be used for Granger causality testing?

Comment: yes you are correct

Comment: Well, 19 looks quite a lot. Is your sample very large? If not, perhaps rely on BIC instead of AIC; BIC will likely suggest a more parsimonious model.

Comment: my sample is monthly data from Apr 83 till Dec 2015. In my case both AIC and BIC is suggesting for lag 1.

Comment: I guess, 1 lag sounds more reasonable than 12 lags for monthly data with roughly 400 observations.